# Chromium css/js support

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chromium

Is there a way to find out what css/js is supported by an embedded chromium browser? For example: I can see I’m using chromium version 47.0.2526.80. Does this infer that js/css support is inline with Chrome version 47?

Comment: Why don't you check out https://caniuse.com/ or https://html5test.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Chrome version 47 is based upon Chromium 47. The only difference is Chrome has Google branding. The browser engine is the same